# Tkinter - pass button grid values between classes upon clicking button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to create a basic Battleship game in Python using Tkinter.

Below is a very simplified version of my code. Essentially I am creating a 10*10 grid of buttons and positioning them using `.grid`. What I'd like to do is click one of those buttons and pass that buttons grid values (x, y) from the `GameBoard` class to the `Battleship` class to position the ship.

I have tried using `self.row = row` and `self.column = column`, however when I do this I immediately receive an attribute error, `'GameBoard' object has no attribute 'row'`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GameBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mw = tk.Tk()
        self.size = 10

    def build_grid(self):
        for x in range(self.size):
            for y in range(self.size):
                self.button = tk.Button(self.mw, text = '', width = 2, height = 1,\
                command = lambda row = x, column = y: self.clicked(row, column))
                self.button.grid(row = x, column = y)
            
    def clicked(self, row, column):
        print(row, column)
        self.row = row
        self.column = column

class Battleship:
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.gboard = board

    def position_ship(self):
        x = self.gboard.row
        y = self.gboard.column
        for i in range (3):
            self.submarine = tk.Button(self.gboard.mw, background = "black", text = '',\
                                   width = 2, height = 1)
            self.submarine.grid(row = x, column = y)
              
def main():
    gboard = GameBoard()
    gboard.build_grid()
    bt = Battleship(gboard)
    bt.position_ship()    
main()
```

Comment: When `bt.position_ship()` is called inside `main()`, `self.row` and `self.column` of `gboard` have not yet created because no button has been clicked.

Comment: @acw1668, how would I call `bt.position_ship()`  after I've clicked a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @acw1668 pointed out in a comment, the problem is the `gboard` attributes `row` and `column` haven't been created yet when you call `bt.position_ship()` in the `main()` function.

I don't know your overall game design, but a very simple way to fix that would be to assign a random board position to them in the `GameBoard.__init__()` method.

I've also modified the code to show how to call `bt.position_ship()` when a button is clicked. This is done by passing the `BattleShip` instance `bt` to the `build_grid()` function so it can be included in calls to the `clicked()` method, which can now call it when its called.

```
from random import randrange
import tkinter as tk

class GameBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mw = tk.Tk()
        self.size = 10
        self.row = randrange(self.size)
        self.column = randrange(self.size)

    def build_grid(self, bt):
        for x in range(self.size):
            for y in range(self.size):
                self.button = tk.Button(self.mw, text='', width=2, height=1,
                                        command=lambda row=x, column=y:
                                            self.clicked(bt, row, column))
                self.button.grid(row=x, column=y)

    def clicked(self, bt, row, column):
        print(row, column)
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        bt.position_ship()


class Battleship:
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.gboard = board

    def position_ship(self):
        x = self.gboard.row
        y = self.gboard.column
        for i in range (3):
            self.submarine = tk.Button(self.gboard.mw, background="black", text='',
                                       width=2, height=1)
            self.submarine.grid(row=x, column=y)


def main():
    gboard = GameBoard()
    bt = Battleship(gboard)
    gboard.build_grid(bt)
    bt.position_ship()
    tk.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you @martineau, I will implement this in my project now.

Comment: You're welcome. Passing the Battleship around like may seem a little awkward, but it's better than using global variables — the lack of them being something that impressed me about your implementation — so I tried very hard to to not introduce any.